# `hostname` result is different from “/etc/hostname”!

Tags: hostname, hosts

If I open a terminal windows in my graphical user interface, `hostname` command result is different from content of `/etc/hostname`:

```
me@ZyXEL1:~$ hostname
ZyXEL1
me@ZyXEL1:~$ cat /etc/hostname
N4010
me@ZyXEL1:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 N4010

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and `sudo` command shows:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ZyXEL1: No such file or directory
```

In tty1, tty2 and ... the command prompt is `me@N4010:~$` instead of wrong one: `me@ZyXEL1:~$`, but `sudo` result is same as terminal window:

```
me@N4010:~$sudo
sudo: unable to resolve host ZyXEL1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just for grins,do a 'command hostname' in case your shell aliases are playing with you?  Happens by accident sometimes. :)

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186859/understand-hostname-and-etc-hosts

Comment: Are you receiving a hostname via DHCP?

Comment: @Kusalananda My system IP address is obtained via DHCP of my wireless router. But how to find if my hostname is coming via DHCP or not?

Comment: It may have been recorded in a log. Unfortunately I would not know where to start looking on your system. I've noticed that my own laptops sometimes are assigned custom hostnames when I connect to some corporate WiFi networks.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think you are right, the problem is related to my office wireless/modem. Because it is a ZyXEL modem. But what is occurring and how to prevent this problem?!

Comment: Check your /bin/hostname -

Answer (score 1):

This may happens when you have just changed the hostname in the /etc/hostname. It is not reflected to hostname yet. You can set the hostname by restart the computer or more simply:

```
hostname ZyXEL1
```

Comment: After restart, the problem disappeared.